# my wireless network is not working. i have my wireless info results. what should i do next?

Tags: 14.04, wireless

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628874/

This is the link to my wireless script info file. 
I do not know how to proceed further.
I tried updating my network drivers but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ethernet appears to be working, in terminal enter `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
Reboot and wifi should be working.  If you look at the end of the wireless-info file you will see that it has firmware problems